# Accidentally changed ALT behaviour

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, shortcuts, language

I've accidentally used some combination that made ALT + something shortcuts not working anymore (ALT + some letter does not make it with accent anymore). The behaviour of the right ALT which was always supposed to enable me writing letters with diacritics now is the same as the left ALT.

How to restore the default settings?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably changed your keyboard settings. Either you have multiple keyboard layouts defined (in which case, hold the WIN key and tap spacebar to change to the next one in the list, and try again).

If this doesn't help, you need to change your keyboard layout. Unfortunately you haven't listed your Windows version, but one of these links should help:

[Windows XP/Vista/7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258824)

[Windows 8 or 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/121169/how-to-change-your-keyboard-layout-in-windows-8/)

Comment: Glad (something) worked for you..!